# Recommended method of escaping single quotes in bash - double quotes, backslashes, or something else?

Tags: bash, escaping

I want to append `alias foo='bar'` to the end of my bash profile directly in the command line and I know of two ways to do it - escaping the single quotes with backslashes, or enclosing the command in double quotes, namely:

1. `echo alias foo=\'bar\' >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. `echo "alias foo='bar'" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Is one method considered "safer" than the other? Both work as expected, but what I'm wondering is if one of these methods has a lower probability of causing unexpected behaviour when used in other ways, or if there is some other recommended way of escaping single quotes (in this specific context) that is the least error-prone.

Comment: what do you mean by "when used in other ways"

Comment: @armando I'm basically inquiring about best practices since both methods seem equally effective on the outside, but there might be something else happening under the hood that only becomes apparent in a different context that I haven't taken into account (e.g. multiline strings). For example, if there's some scenario I'm not accounting for where escaping with backslashes is better/worse than enclosing them in double quotes because it results in something unexpected, e.g. shell expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two commands are slightly different, in that `echo alias foo=\'bar\'` passes two arguments to `echo` (namely `alias` and `foo='bar'`), while `echo "alias foo='bar'"` passes only one (namely `alias foo='bar'`). Since `echo` prints all of its arguments separated by spaces, this amounts to the same thing in your case, but it's worth keeping in mind in the general case.

But then, with the actual command that you've posted, your single-quotes aren't needed anyway — the command `alias foo='bar'` is equivalent to the command `alias foo=bar` — so the normal way to write it is:

```
echo 'alias foo=bar' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

In the more general case, where `bar` could be any command, I'd still wrap the whole thing in single-quotes to ensure no stray expansions or word-splitting takes place, writing e.g.:

```
echo 'alias foo='\''command with * and ? and spaces'\' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

(whereas your first version, applied to such a command, would misbehave terribly; your second version would handle this case fine, but would still break if there are parameter expansions or whatnot in the command being aliased).

Answer (score 0):

a scenario which could lead to difficulties is if you tried to write
the lines you mentioned into a file:

```
file.txt << !
echo alias foo=\'bar\' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "alias foo='bar'" >> ~/.bash_profile
!
```

you can check file.txt to see if the output is what you expect.