# character-escaping double quotes in bash append file of command and output

Tags: bash, shell, printf, escaping, echo

I work with a variety of diagnostic files (text / `jq` for JSON / `yq` for YAML / `xpath` for XML, `lnav` for log files) in Bash where I need to dynamically determine meaningful data parsing before reporting the final command and its output.

A bit ago as [written-up here](https://stefnestor.github.io/labs/bash-report-append/) after I found out via [Echoing the last command run in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/echoing-the-last-command-run-in-bash) that I could use `!!` to run the previous command and stash its results to a file.

The problem I've encountered is an edge-case that when the ran command uses double-quotes they get omitted when stashed:

```bash
$ echo "hello"
hello
$ echo "!!" >> test && !! >> test
echo "echo "hello"" >> test && echo "hello" >> test
$ cat test
echo hello # no double-quotes
hello      # but right answer
```

I've attempted but failed so far to compensate for this via

- [Escape sequences with "echo -e" in different shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/escape-sequences-with-echo-e-in-different-shells) use `-e` to have `echo` character-escape for you
- [How can I escape double quotes in content gotten from file](https://serverfault.com/questions/850371/how-can-i-escape-double-quotes-in-content-gotten-from-file), [BASH escaping double quotes within single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181508/bash-escaping-double-quotes-within-single-quotes) manual character-escape via`sed`
- [How can I escape double quotes in content gotten from file](https://serverfault.com/questions/850371/how-can-i-escape-double-quotes-in-content-gotten-from-file), [While using printf how to escape special characters in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958430/while-using-printf-how-to-escape-special-characters-in-shell-script) use `printf` with `%b` or `%s`
- ([site](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-append-to-file)) use `tee`
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/562080/7938558 use `""` instead of `"` on inner double-quotes
- [Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file) use `script`

The one that's worked best is `script`, except A) I only need to retain <5% of commands/output ran & B) I haven't figured out to load my Dotfiles (though I assume that answer lies in `man script`'s `SCRIPT` or `SHELL` environment variables which I'd investigate further if that's the best bet).

My problem specifically becomes non-cosmetic and interruptive when asking others to repeat queries I've compiled (for example, to monitor resolution steps effectiveness):

```
# what I would run
$ echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")'
a-a

# how I would cache for others to run
$ echo "!!" >> test && !! >> test
echo "echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")'" >> test && echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")' >> test

# this command does not work unless !! is within double quotes which partially seems to induce the issue

# what stored to file for others to run
$ cat test
echo '[a-a,b-a]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.==a-a)'
a-a


# command will error for others because double-quotes dropped
$ echo '[a-a,b-a]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.==a-a)'
jq: error: a/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[]|select(.==a-a)
jq: error: a/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[]|select(.==a-a)
jq: 2 compile errors
```

What I expect / hope is

- there's a flag in either `echo` or `printf` that character-escapes the double-quotes when running `"!!"` or avoids `!!` needing the double-quotes
- there's a way to run `script` (with Dotfiles) to just "run and stash the very last command" (instead of reporting everything and then after manually deleting most of the session)

What I'm not interested in (since I work across Operating Systems and can't guarantee other's installations/environments)

- Jupyter Notebook has a [Bash kernel](https://pypi.org/project/bash_kernel/) that I could use and then manually copy/paste into a text file
- Bash is the most common scripting language across Operating Systems, so while I love Python and `ipython` would answer very close to my request, my folks aren't guaranteed to have Python installed so it's a no-go.
- advice to error-handle when double-quotes was involved to manually stash the command+output; I have this now just not in the above write-up
- needing to write the original query in single-quotes with single-quote escaping to then use `"!!"` without it dropping double-quotes. That works in a lot of places (and I do it though annoyed) but single-quote-escaping causes issues using [Salesforce's CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm).

I reviewed Stack Overflow's recommended questions but did not think they answered:

- [How can I escape double quotes in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586627/how-can-i-escape-double-quotes-in-bash)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36878068/7938558
- [escaping double quotes in external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147410/escaping-double-quotes-in-external-command)
- [Recommended method of escaping single quotes in bash - double quotes, backslashes, or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632487/recommended-method-of-escaping-single-quotes-in-bash-double-quotes-backslashe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!` by itself does not swallow any quotes. It happens when the shell is interpreting the substitute literally, which includes resolving quoted content. `"!!"` doesn't do more than wrapping double quotes around it, which still just contributes to the interpretation by the shell but now it also easily interferes with quotes coming from the previous command.

A better way would be to retrieve the last command by other means, e.g. `history`. There are several ways to filter for the last one, here are some examples:

```bash
$ echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")'
a-a

$ cmd="$(history -- -2 | head -n1 | cut -c8-)"
```

```bash
$ echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")'
a-a

$ cmd="$(history -w /dev/stdout | tail -n2 | head -n1)"
```

```bash
$ echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")'
a-a

$ cmd="$(HISTTIMEFORMAT="$(echo -e '\r\e[K')" history -- -2 | head -n1)"
```

All these examples assign the content of the last command to a shell variable:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' "$cmd"
echo '["a-a","b-a"]' | jq -rc '.[]|select(.=="a-a")'
```

Alternatively, instead of using an assignment `cmd="$(…)"`, you can also redirect it to a file, e.g. `… > file`, or pipe it into the another processor, e.g. `… | sh`, etc.

Comment: This is perfect, cheers <3